# Makefile: Removing a list of files matching several truncated filenames from another list

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a Makefile, I want to remove a list of files matching a pattern made of filenames prefixed with test_, from another list.

Let us take this Makefile which is doing what I want (just not the way I want):

```
SRC_FILES = \
    src/path/a.c \
    src/path/b.c \
    src/path/c.c \
    src/path/d.c

TEST_FILES = \
    test/another_path/test_b.c \
    test/another_path/test_c.c \

RESULTING_FILES = \
    $(TEST_FILES) \
    $(filter-out src/path/b.c src/path/c.c,$(SRC_FILES))

all:
    @echo SOURCE FILES:
    @echo $(SRC_FILES)
    @echo ""
    @echo TEST FILES:
    @echo $(TEST_FILES)
    @echo ""
    @echo RESULTING FILES:
    @echo $(RESULTING_FILES)
```

Let us run make all:

> SOURCE FILES: src/path/a.c src/path/b.c src/path/c.c src/path/d.c
>
> TEST FILES: test/another_path/test_b.c test/another_path/test_c.c
>
> RESULTING FILES: test/another_path/test_b.c test/another_path/test_c.c
>   src/path/a.c src/path/d.c

We can see the resulting files are made of:

- all the test files
- the source files after removing the ones which match one of the test files filename without the prefix test_.

To remove the source files I do not want, I use the following line:
`$(filter-out src/path/b.c src/path/c.c,$(SRC_FILES))`

As you can see, the files I want to remove are hardcoded.
How could I get the same result as this previous line but without hardcoding the filepath/filenames?
The goal is to remove the source files for which there is an equivalent test file (a.c <-> test_a.c).

EDIT: I did not explained it initially but the path of the source files can be different for each file, e.g.:

```
SRC_FILES = \
    src/path_1/a.c \
    src/path_2/b.c \
    src/path_1/next_path/c.c \
    src/path_4/d.c
```

Comment: You may take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) for the function `glob-match` which can do a more flexible pattern match than the builtin make `%` wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the test files into a pattern matching the file name:

```
TEST_PATTERNS = $(addprefix %/,$(patsubst test_%,%,$(notdir $(TEST_FILES))))
```

Now you can use filter-out:

```
$(filter-out $(TEST_PATTERNS),$(SRC_FILES))
```

Or if you really want a specific path not a pattern you can use `$(addprefix src/path/,$(...))`